# Redirect file path for specific executable?

Tags: files, io-redirection

Assume the I have an executable `a.exe` which wants to accecss path `/aaa/bbb/` but has no permission.

Is there any way to make `a.exe` feel for example`~/bbb/` like `/aaa/bbb/`? i.e., something like a wrapper.

My system platform is CentOS 7.3.

By the way, redirect file access into memory is also acceptable.

Comment: Any wrapper or technique will be platform-dependent, so you'll need to [edit] your question to say what your target platforms are.

Comment: Updated as your comment, thanks @Michael Homer

Comment: It's easy to set `HOME` to `/aaa` to allow resolving `~/bbb` into `/aaa/bbb` (if the program does its own tilde expansion), but it would not solve permission issues. For that, you would either have to change the permissions on the directory, or run the program as a user that has permissions to access the directory.

Comment: I read the question as wanting the opposite. The program is hardcoded to read `/aaa/bbb` and the OP wants it to read `~/bbb`. I think it might be possible with mount namespaces (and bind mounts), but I have no experience with those, so I'm not able to give any suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: @Henrik 's understanding is correct.  "The program is hardcoded to read /aaa/bbb and the OP wants it to read ~/bbb", that is what I want.